# Inverse Laplace transform to $e^{-s^2}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, laplace-transform

Does $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{e^{-s^2} \}(t) $ or equivalently, $$f(t)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma - i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} e^{st}e^{-s^2} ds$$ exist under closed form?

Comment: Nope ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: For a weakly integrable function on the positive real line it is pretty uncommon to have an *entire* Laplace transform. Additionally, if $f(x)\geq 0$ then $\mathcal{L} f$ is log-convex, while $e^{-s^2}$ is log-*concave*. What is the original problem involving such inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: It does turn out, though, that $F(s)=e^{s^2}$ has a two-sided ILT, that is, over $t \in (-\infty,\infty)$.